# css for text box and image displayed in same line

Tags: html, css

I want to display the text box and image in same line.Now I adjust the pixel set to chrome.In firefox some difference is occur.I draw the text box in black color box and image in red color round.green line is how they are in same position.

```css
.per
{
 float:right;
 margin-right:38%;
}
p {
   font-family:arial;
 font-size:13px;
 font-weight:bold;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left:20%;
}
```

```html
<p>Company Name<input type="text" name="s" size=18 maxlength=50  readonly value="sample"> </p>       
                       <p> Title<input type="text" name="s" size=18 maxlength=50 readonly value="title"> </p>
                        <p>Start Date<input type="text" name="s" size=18 maxlength=50 readonly value="date"> </p>
                        <p>End Date<input type="text" name="s" size=18 maxlength=50 readonly value="date1"> </p>
                      <p>Pay Rate<input type="text" name="s" size=18 maxlength=50  readonly value=" pay rate "> </p>
                        <h3 style="align:left">Permission
                        
                      
                              <span id="per" class="per">
                               <img src="image/tick.png" alt="tick" style="width:15px;height:15px">
                               </span></h3>
```

I want to display this by calculating the text starting position rather than calculating margin-right.
I attached screen shot for image displayed in chrome and in fire fox.

chrome

[image]

firefox

[image]

layout to be wanted
    [image]

Comment: check my answer  and please tell me the result

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a Div or a Table and have your content placed appropriately.

You can also use Bootstrap3, Foundation or other CSS frameworks to make this look neat and responsive.

Answer (score 0):

use following css code

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

p {
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left:20%;
}
.maincontainer{
        position: relative; 

    }

.names{
    display: inline;
    position: relative; 
    left: 50px;
    margin:5px; 
}

.namescontent{
    display: inline;
    position: absolute ;
    left: 200;
    margin:5px; 
}
```

And following html code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="maincontainer"> 
        <div class="names">Company Name</div> <div class="namescontent">    <input type="text" name="s" size=18 maxlength=50  readonly value="sample"> </div> <br>
        <div class="names"> Title</div>     <div class="namescontent"><input type="text" name="s" size=18 maxlength=50 readonly value="title"> </div>
        <br>
        <div class="names">Start Date</div> <div class="namescontent">  <input type="text" name="s" size=18 maxlength=50 readonly value="date"> </div>
        <br>
        <div class="names">End Date</div>   <div class="namescontent">  <input type="text" name="s" size=18 maxlength=50 readonly value="date1"> </div>
        <br>
        <div class="names">Pay Rate</div>   <div class="namescontent">  <input type="text" name="s" size=18 maxlength=50  readonly value=" pay rate "> </div>
        <br>
        </div>
        <h3 style="align:left">Permission               


                <div class="namescontent"><img src="image/tick.png" alt="tick" style="width:15px;height:15px"></div>
            </h3>

    </body>     
</html>
```

Comment: I am having this inside table tag.So having problem with alignment

Comment: plz copy and paste in in snippet.I mashed.

Comment: @user3386779 - sorry i cant get you.

Comment: I copied and paste your code in snippet but get mashed.so try this code in snippet.

Comment: In my local pc i run the code. It is working fine in chrome, firefox and IE. Try to run that code in local pc (not in snippet)